# How to abstract bigram topics instead of unigrams using Latent Dirichlet Allocation (LDA) in python- gensim?

Tags: nlp, text-mining, lda, gensim

## LDA Original Output

- Uni-grams

  - topic1 -scuba,water,vapor,diving
  - topic2 -dioxide,plants,green,carbon

## Required Output

- Bi-gram topics

  - topic1 -scuba diving,water vapor
  - topic2 -green plants,carbon dioxide

Any idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use word2vec to get most similar terms from the top n topics abstracted using LDA.

LDA Output

Create a dictionary of bi-grams using topics abstracted  (for ex:-san_francisco)

check http://www.markhneedham.com/blog/2015/02/12/pythongensim-creating-bigrams-over-how-i-met-your-mother-transcripts/

Then, do word2vec to get most similar words (uni-grams,bi-grams etc)

**Word**      and           **Cosine distance**

los_angeles               (0.666175)
golden_gate               (0.571522)
oakland                   (0.557521)

check https://code.google.com/p/word2vec/  (From words to phrases and beyond)

Answer (score 9):

Given I have a dict called `docs`, containing lists of words from documents, I can turn it into an array of words + bigrams (or also trigrams etc.) using nltk.util.ngrams or your own function like this:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

for doc in docs:
    docs[doc] = docs[doc] + ["_".join(w) for w in ngrams(docs[doc], 2)]
```

Then you pass the values of this dict to the LDA model as a corpus. Bigrams joined by underscores are thus treated as single tokens.