# Capture bigram topics instead of unigrams using latent dirichlet allocat

Tags: python, nltk, gensim, n-gram

I try to make an attempt like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32476336/how-to-abstract-bigram-topics-instead-of-unigrams-using-latent-dirichlet-allocat) question

LDA Original Output

```
Uni-grams

    topic1 -scuba,water,vapor,diving

    topic2 -dioxide,plants,green,carbon
```

Required Output

```
Bi-gram topics

    topic1 -scuba diving,water vapor

    topic2 -green plants,carbon dioxide
```

And there is this answer

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

for doc in docs:
    docs[doc] = docs[doc] + ["_".join(w) for w in ngrams(docs[doc], 2)]
```

Any help what update should I make in order to have only bigrams?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create only documents with bigrams:

```
from nltk.util import ngrams

for doc in docs:
    docs[doc] = ["_".join(w) for w in ngrams(docs[doc], 2)]
```

Or specific method for bigrams:

```
from nltk.util import bigrams

for doc in docs:
    docs[doc] = ["_".join(w) for w in bigrams(docs[doc])]
```

Then use lists of these bigrams in `texts` for future operations.